# PostgreSQL - How to use For loop and Return statement in a User-defined function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to count duplicate rows such that the function only gives the redundant count not the whole count, for example: when a row appears three times and the count function returns 3, the row is only redundant by 2 extra occurences; therefore, the function should return 2 and then sum up the redundant counts to get the total number of duplicate rows. Below is my code

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_duplicates()
 RETURNS SETOF INTEGER
 AS $BODY$
 BEGIN
     WITH total AS (
         SELECT brand, naira_price, city, state, phone_condition, color, COUNT(*) AS qty
         FROM phones
         GROUP BY brand, naira_price, city, state, phone_condition, color
         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     )

     FOR i IN (a.qty) as dup
     LOOP
         RETURN QUERY SUM(i-1) FROM total a;
     END LOOP;
 END;
 $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function returns an error message instead `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FOR"`
`LINE 12:     FOR i IN (a.qty) as dup` Help is appreciated.

Comment: Half your CTE is missing, that's why it complains about the FOR. But to be honest, why would you use a LOOP for this? A simple SQL function is good enough. At least when you use valid SQL inside this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the clue from @Laurenz Albe answer -- thanks, I have gotten the solution to my question:

```
WITH total AS (
    SELECT brand, naira_price, city, state, phone_condition, color,
        (COUNT(*) - 1) AS qty
    FROM phones
    GROUP BY brand, naira_price, city, state, phone_condition, color
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT SUM(a.qty) AS duplicate_rows FROM total a;
```

This sums up the duplicate rows in the table and returns a single value of the summation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix SQL and PL/pgSQL in a single statement. But according to your description, you want this query:

```
SELECT brand, naira_price, city, state, phone_condition, color,
       COUNT(*) - 1 AS superfluous
FROM phones
GROUP BY brand, naira_price, city, state, phone_condition, color
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```